# S3 - Eventual Consistency and multiple clients

Tags: get, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, put, eventual-consistency

If I PUT an object in S3 (US East) and then repeatedly request the object's metadata until I can GET it, then at that point am I guaranteed that all other clients can now GET the object?  OR is it possible that another client's request is somehow routed to a different server that has not yet registered the PUT?  I'm trying to understand the consequence of eventual consistency specifically in the case where one client has been able to GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 does not provide any specific guarantees as to when all replicas converge and all GETs are guaranteed to return the latest data; this is because, if a network partition were to occur between S3 replicas, replication could be delayed until the partition is repaired. However usually consistency is acheived within seconds.